# Fedora VNC problem- getting a grey screen with three checkboxes

Tags: fedora, x11, vnc

I have set up VNC using [this guide](http://stufs4u.wordpress.com/2014/02/25/install-and-configure-vnc-server-in-fedora-20/), however, despite all my efforts, I can't seem to progress beyond this stage:
[image: grey screen and checkboxes] with three checkboxes saying "Accept Clipboard from Viewers", "Send Clipboard to Viewers" and "Send Primary selection to viewers".

I have researched this topic on the internet, and it is apparently something to do with my `~/.vnc/xstartup` file, which currently looks like this:

```
#!/bin/sh

unset SESSION_MANAGER
exec /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc
```

on my selected user (i.e. I haven't changed the settings for the wrong user account). I have restarted VNC several times to no avail.

I don't have physical access to the computer since it is on a VPS. I am running Fedora 20.

Comment: What's the screen you have attached? Is it a VNC client screen after a successful connection to your server?

Comment: @SebastianPiech Yep

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed this [tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-vnc-remote-access-for-the-gnome-desktop-on-centos-7)

And also changed `/etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc` to point the window manager I am using & executed it (in my case for ***XFCE*** this was `exec /bin/sh /etc/xdg/xfce4/xinitrc`)

Re-booted the server and it now works.